There is an error while opening an ipynb file
I am trying to open the file Ch02-statlearn-lab.ipynb but I am getting File Load Error.
I have installed jupyter and notebook and after I enter the command python -m notebook , the server starts in the browser. This is a file from a famous book on Data Science. So, I don't think there is any error in the file itself. What could be the reason for this error ?

Could you please elaborate.  it is working fine for me
Download raw file from the github
if you have installed jupyter notebook in your system just go to terminal
type
jupyter notebook

then the browser will open just upload the file you downloaded there .

wow. I downloaded the raw file and it worked like a charm.  But I used the command python -m notebook.  If I type jupyter notebook, then I get the error 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. How do I add jupyter to the PATH ?

anyway. figured it out. working as needed. Thank a ton !!
